# what port is tomcat 6 running on

Tags: apache2, tomcat6

I have installed a package called opengeo-suite which installs tomcat 6 if it is not installed. Now I have apache 2.2 running on port 8080. I wish to find out on which port is the tomcat 6 running on? What is the command to find that out?

**EDIT**

Also how do I identify whether it is up and running?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you use

```
$ ps -ef
```

or

```
$ top
```

you should be able to find the PID (Process ID) for your opengeo-suite.

With the PID in hand, you can use netstat and grep to find out what port it's running on. For example, I can see the PID of my tomcat is 1483. So using,

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 1483
```

I get the result:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1483/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      1483/java
```

I don't think you asked this, but for completeness, to find the process ID when you know port number:

```
$ sudo lsof -i:8080 -n
```

gives

```
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    1483 tomcat6   36u  IPv6   3496      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

*Note, netstat and lsof will run without sudo, but they won't show all ports. In my case, sudo was necessary to see the tomcat ports.*

Comment: I like that find-process-from-port trick! Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

[By default it runs on port 8080](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/tomcat.html)

You can scan your ports and other's ports by using "nmap"

For your own machine:

```
nmap localhost
```

Comment: For your local machine `netstat` would be much easier and faster. Read the man page on how to connect the name of the program that opens the port to the output. `man netstat` is one of your friends here:-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ohno, It has a very good and friendly manual.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below:

```
netstat -ntpl | grep java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:**8005**          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2710/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:**8008**            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2710/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:**8009**            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2710/java
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details what is this supposed to do and why. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)